# Electricity is a wave of electron. But my question is from where the electrons come and where do they go?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electricity, electrons, flow

We know that electricity is a wave of electrons bit from where do they come and where do they go? Does electricity have mass?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, usually electricity is a current of electrons, generally, it is a current of free charged particles, be it electrons, cations, or something else. The electricity itself cannot have mass since it is by definition just a current, however, *the particles that make current possible* have mass, in the case of electrons, $m_e=9.1\cdot 10^{-31}\rm\, kg$.

Electrons emerge from the negative terminal of a battery or current source (in the DC case), and travel along the wires to the positive terminal. There, a work is done on them in order to bring them through the battery to the negative terminal. This work can be done by [chemical reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_cell), or by an external energy source.

However, don't think that these electrons travel through the wires with nearly speed of light. The thermal speed of electrons (the speed because of temperature) is around $10^6 \rm\, \frac{m}{s}$, but this corresponds to random movement in all directions. The systematic speed to the positive terminal (that causes electricity) is ordinarily on order of $1\rm\,\frac{mm}{s}$. How can then the lightbulb turn almost instantly when you press on the switch? The answer is that the energy is not carried by electrons (not as red blood cells carry oxygen), but by electric fields caused by electrons. That's why you don't have to wait half an hour for the light to turn on.